# Publishing to CocoaPods from Travis

Tags: git, cocoapods, travis-ci

How would you go about pushing to CocoaPods from Travis? I would like for each tagged commit to do a `pod trunk push`, but is it a good idea to `pod trunk register` Travis? Trunk's docs say it registers a machine, rather than a user, so would that inadvertently open up the Pod to pushes from other people who use Travis?

Does anyone have an example of a repo that's already doing this?

You can do this with RubyGems using private API keys pushed with the Travis command line tool, as described in [RubyGems Deployment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/rubygems/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cocoapods** support authentication with a **Token**.

First, you need get the **Token** from the password field of `~/.netrc`. After calling `pod trunk register`, you'll see a section that looks like this:

```
machine trunk.cocoapods.org
   login user@example.com
   password 0000000011111111
```

Then you can update podspec on CI with the **Token** (which is insecure):

```
export COCOAPODS_TRUNK_TOKEN=0000000011111111
pod trunk push path/to.podspec
```

You can also encrypt the **Token** in Travis-CI with

```
travis encrypt COCOAPODS_TRUNK_TOKEN=0000000011111111 --add env
```

**Update**

You can now set environment variable directly in your plan's Settings. If you turn off **Display value in build log** (which is disabled by default), it treats it as a secure variable. That way, you don't need to mess with the Travis command line tools, or add junk to your yaml file, and can make changes without altering your repo.

[image: Travis environment variables]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Quanlong for info regarding in which file the password can be found.

You can extract the password from said file using this command

```
grep -s password ~/.netrc | awk '{print $2}'
```

So if you are using [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) or any other CI suite you can set the token like this

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_TRUNK_TOKEN'] = sh "grep -s password ~/.netrc | awk '{print $2}'"
```

Which works in fastlane. Otherwise you might wanna call the `grep` command in some other way, maybe `system("grep ... ")`